# How to run the Konami code in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have created a PowerShell script (GUI form), and I have all the functionality I want working.

But is it possible to run Konami code in a PowerShell script?

If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: Could you clarify what is the 'Konami code'..? Do you mean The Konami Code: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code?

Comment: You sort of want to setup a key logger? So, when the correct sequence of keys are pressed you give the user 999 lives. [Here's a key logger of PowerShell](https://code.google.com/p/nishang/source/browse/trunk/Keylogger.ps1) I'm sure you can edit it to check for the correct sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like [this](http://www.vexasoft.com/pages/send-keyboardinput). It's third party, so use at your own risk.